# Cannot change fonts on Algorithms Table of Contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

In the MWE below, I cannot change the font (and formatting) of the Table of Contents for the "List of Algorithms" page.  As you will see, the font for the TOC is `\sffamily`, however, when I try the same formatting to the algorithms page, nothing happens.  Can you help me format the List of Algorithms contents page to match the other List of contents page?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents
\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
{\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of listings
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of Algorithms
\contentsuse{algorithms}{lol}
\titlecontents{algorithms}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\large\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{This is a description for Figure 1}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{This is a description for Figure 2}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\chapter{List of Matlab Algorithms}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training 2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training 3}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
\titlecontents{algocf}
```

because the package `algorithm2e` stores the captions as

```
\contentsline{algocf}{...}
```

in the `.loa` file. However, this package doesn't seem to be wanting to cooperate with `titletoc` that's unable to initialize one of its variables, so we need to give some help.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{52,177,201}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
  {\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
  {\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}} % Chapter number
  {\color{ocre}}
  {\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
  {\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
  {}
  {\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
  []

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
  {\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
  []

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
  {\addvspace{-5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

% List of listings
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

% List of Algorithms
\contentsuse{algorithms}{lol}
\titlecontents{algocf}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\makeatletter
% for some reasons, \ttll@algocf is not initialized
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\ttll@algocf{-1000}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Problem}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Problem Statement 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{This is a description for Figure 1}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\caption{This is a description for Figure 2}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\chapter{List of Matlab Algorithms}
\section{Algorithm 1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training 2}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
some text here
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training 3}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\chapter{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]