# Cannot change fonts on Algorithms Table of Contents page part 2

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

This question is building from the [solution found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306200/cannot-change-fonts-on-algorithms-table-of-contents-page).

From the solution given by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), I am still not getting my code to compile.

Please help me to compile the following code so that I can have control of the List of Algorithms TOC to change its fonts etc.

When I run this code, I get the error:
`LaTeX Error: Command \l@algocf already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal,...`

`l.2476 ...l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2.3em}}
                                                  % line of the list
?`

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{199,232,250}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{59,134,215}

%======================================================================================
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{darkblue!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{darkblue}} % Chapter number
{\color{darkblue}}
{\color{darkblue!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of listings
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of Algorithms
\contentsuse{algorithms}{lol}
\titlecontents{algocf}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

\makeatletter
% for some reasons, \ttll@algocf is not initialized
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\ttll@algocf{-1000}}
\makeatother

%======================================================================================
%   ALGORITHM
%======================================================================================

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Algorithms}

\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\let\@@thealgoline\theAlgoLine
\newif\ifuseothernumbering
\newcounter{SubAlgoLine}
\renewcommand{\theSubAlgoLine}{\@@thealgoline\alph{SubAlgoLine}}
\renewcommand{\theAlgoLine}{%
  \ifuseothernumbering
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=3
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \else
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=4
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}
  \addtocounter{AlgoLine}{\m@ne}%
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \global\useothernumberingfalse
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%
  \fi
  \fi
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\bfseries\color{darkblue}}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\bfseries\itshape\color{darkblue}}

\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}

\begin{document}

%========================================================================================
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%========================================================================================

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Algorithms}

\colorbox{green!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{8}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
Normalization of eigenfaces
\begin{equation*}
  E_{n} = E_{s}\begin{bmatrix}
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{1}} &  &  & \\
                 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{2}} & &\bigzero \\
                  \bigzero &  &  \ddots & \\
                  & &  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{M-1}}\\
               \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}\\
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\colorbox{green!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{8}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
Normalization of eigenfaces
\begin{equation*}
  E_{n} = E_{s}\begin{bmatrix}
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{1}} &  &  & \\
                 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{2}} & &\bigzero \\
                  \bigzero &  &  \ddots & \\
                  & &  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{M-1}}\\
               \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}\\
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load all the packages before starting to change the setting.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{199,232,250}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{59,134,215}

%======================================================================================
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%======================================================================================


\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{darkblue!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{darkblue}} % Chapter number
{\color{darkblue}}
{\color{darkblue!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of listings
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[0em]
{\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of Algorithms
\contentsuse{algorithms}{lol}
\titlecontents{algocf}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

\makeatletter
% for some reasons, \ttll@algocf is not initialized
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\ttll@algocf{-1000}}
\makeatother

%======================================================================================
%   ALGORITHM
%======================================================================================

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Algorithms}

\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line number for one line
\let\@@thealgoline\theAlgoLine
\newif\ifuseothernumbering
\newcounter{SubAlgoLine}
\renewcommand{\theSubAlgoLine}{\@@thealgoline\alph{SubAlgoLine}}
\renewcommand{\theAlgoLine}{%
  \ifuseothernumbering
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=3
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \else
  \ifnum\c@AlgoLine=4
  \protect\refstepcounter{SubAlgoLine}
  \addtocounter{AlgoLine}{\m@ne}%
  \theSubAlgoLine%
  \global\useothernumberingfalse
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%
  \fi
  \fi
  \else
  \@@thealgoline%
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\bfseries\color{darkblue}}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\bfseries\itshape\color{darkblue}}

\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}

\begin{document}

%========================================================================================
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%========================================================================================

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Algorithms}

\colorbox{green!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{8}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
Normalization of eigenfaces
\begin{equation*}
  E_{n} = E_{s}\begin{bmatrix}
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{1}} &  &  & \\
                 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{2}} & &\bigzero \\
                  \bigzero &  &  \ddots & \\
                  & &  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{M-1}}\\
               \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}\\
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\colorbox{green!05}{\color{black}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{8}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
Normalization of eigenfaces
\begin{equation*}
  E_{n} = E_{s}\begin{bmatrix}
                 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{1}} &  &  & \\
                 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{2}} & &\bigzero \\
                  \bigzero &  &  \ddots & \\
                  & &  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}_{M-1}}\\
               \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}\\
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Principal Component Analysis (PCA) Training }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```